# How to provide optional value for variable which value evaluates to boolean false?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a fields array which I use to set a result object. If the field is empty, then result uses the existing value of the field:

```
form: {
  fields: [{
    name: 'name',
    value: 'Peter'
  } , {
    name: 'age',
    value: 0
  }]
}

form.fields.forEach(field => {
  result[field.name] = field.value ||
     original.value
}
```

I think you can see the problem: `value: 0` is never set in result because it's evaluated as false.

What the usual solution for cases like this? When you need `0` to be evaluated as `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if value is `undefined` by doing `field.value !== undefined`:

```
form.fields.forEach(field => result[field.name] = field.value !== undefined ? field.value : original.value);
```

Code example:

```js
let zero = 0;

console.log(zero !== undefined ? zero : 'other value');
```

Comment: So the `typeof` is unnecessary?

Comment: Yes, you can Test if a variable is `undefined` by doing: `x === undefined`

Answer (score 1):

```
parseInt(val) === 0
```

the `===` checks the type (int) as well

or you can try

```
typeof field.value != 'undefined'
```

this will evaluate 0 as true and only `undefined` as false

Answer (score 1):

This way you can be sure that your field has **no value at all**, not only `0` but `""` empty string as well.

```
form.fields.forEach(field => {
  if( typeof field.value !== "undefined" ) {
      result[field.name] = field.value
  } else {
      result[field.name] = original.value;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

as suggested in comments by [@Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling), shorter version using ternary operator:

```
 form.fields.forEach(field => {
   result[field.name] = typeof field.value !== "undefined" ? field.value : original.value; 
}
```

Comment: Or a bit more concise: `result[field.name] = typeof field.value !== 'undefined' ? field.value : original.value;`.